# Disable community features in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to disable the community features from the WSO2 API Manager? This is the section in an API that allows a use to 'share' the API via email or social media sites. I have looked through the documentation and the `api-manager.xml` configuration file but can't seem to find out how. I have already been able to disable the comments, ratings and forum but can't seem to disable the social media parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no configuration to remove that section from UI. But you can modify the theme by [subtheme approach](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+new+API+Store+Theme#AddingaNewAPIStoreTheme-Writingasubthemeofthemaintheme). Here is what you have to do.

1) Put a copy of below file to a new subtheme directory as mentioned in above doc.

```
<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/templa
tes/api/overview/template.jag
```

2) Remove social links section from that file.

3) Configure new subtheme in site.json.